# How to load into JSON data into Tableview with help of struct using Swift?

Tags: swift

My scenario, In my project I am getting `JSON` data with help of struct. Here, I can able to get all the `JSON` data. Now I need to load every index `multiple` values in a `array` and load It into `tableview`.

NOTE: I am having search bar also - Search by name

My JSON

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": “name list",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Afrikaans",
            "image": "https://www.google.com/",
            "code": "af",
            “mob_code": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Albanian",
            "image": "https://www.google.com/",
            "code": "sq",
            “mob_code": null
        }
    ]
}
```

My Code

```
  let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("returning error", error);
                        return
                    }

                    do {
                        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(LanguagesData.self, from:data!)
                        //print("RESPONSE:\(result)")
            } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
```

Comment: Do you have a decoding problem or what ? you need a reload

Comment: I am done struct to decode everything. Now I need to know how to load it into tableview. @Sh_Khan

Comment: idk your inner strict name so replace it

Answer (score 1):

**Correct json**

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": "name list",
    "result": [{
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Afrikaans",
            "image": "https://www.google.com/",
            "code": "af",
            "mob_code": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Albanian",
            "image": "https://www.google.com/",
            "code": "sq",
            "mob_code": null
        }
    ]
}
```

**Create an instance variable**

```
var arr = [Inner]()
```

**Decoding**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let res = try decoder.decode(Root.self,from:data)   
arr = res.result 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

**Models**

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status, statusCode: Int
    let message: String
    let result: [Inner]
}

struct Inner: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: URL
    let code: String
    let mobCode: String?
}
```

---

**Table dataSource & delegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! <#CellName#>
    let item = arr[indexPath.row]
    cell.student_label.text = item.name
    cell.photo.sd_setImage(with:item.image, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
}
```

**Test:**

```
    let str = """
{
    "status": 1,
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": "name list",
    "result": [{
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Afrikaans",
            "image": "https://www.google.com/",
            "code": "af",
            "mob_code": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Albanian",
            "image": "https://www.google.com/",
            "code": "sq",
            "mob_code": null
        }
    ]
}
"""

    do {


        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let res = try decoder.decode(Root.self,from:Data(str.utf8))
      print(res)
    }
    catch {

        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: I am already using this...Can u please check this is correct one? struct studentData: Codable {
    let status, statusCode: Int
    let message: String
    let result: [Result]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case statusCode = "status_code"
        case message, result
    }
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, code: String
    let mobcode: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name = "name"
        case code = "code"
        case mobcode = "code"
    }
}

Comment: you use `LanguagesData` in question and post  `studentData` ?? BTW use above structs to make use of `convertToSnakeCase` instead of  `CodingKey`

Comment: install https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage pod and use above code

Comment: Your struct code showing error @sh_Khan. keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "statusCode", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"statusCode\", intValue: nil) (\"statusCode\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: you forget `decoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase` look carefully in answer

Comment: Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'JSONDecoder' line at let result = try! decoder(Root.self,from:data) @Sh_Khan

Comment: Again getting error keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "result", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\name\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: My old codable working well. @Sh_Khan Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not recommended to go with codingKeys use `let decoder = JSONDecoder() ; decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase;let res = try decoder.decode(Root.self,from:data) `

Comment: @jackios copy paste test part and see , it should work as expected , your current json is invalid check it here to verify https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: your models showing same error. I checked my JSON valid one.

Comment: copy your json in question and check it here https://jsonlint.com/ and hit validateJson you'' see errors Test part proves that this is correct

Comment: yes that's just mock JSON. But original one not working by your models. @Sh_Khan